# Query the generic type definition of a class implementing a generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, types, interface, covariance

I've got a C# generic interface `interface IMonitor<in T> where T:IEvent`

So a Monitor is supposed to be of a generic `Event` type

Then I've got a class that has a collection of Monitors

`List<IMonitor<IEvent>> monitors`

I'm adding implementations of `IMonitor<IEvent>` to it. E.g. `monitors.Add(new AConcreteMonitor<AConcreteEvent>())`

Now, in a `Trigger(IEvent event)` method, I want to iterate over the monitor collection and notify all monitors that are of the same generic type as the `event`.

I've got:

```
void Trigger(IEvent event)
    foreach (var monitor in monitors)
        {
            if (
                monitor.GetType()
                    .GetInterfaces()
                    .Any(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == event.GetType()))
            {
                monitor.Notify(event);
            }
        }
}
```

*(avoided LINQ to simplify debugging...)*

The condition never evaluates to true even though there are `AConcreteMonitor<AConcreteEvent>` monitors in the collection and the triggering `event` is `AConcreteEvent`. When debugging it, `GetGenericTypeDefinition()` evaluates to `IMonitor'1`.

Q U E S T I O N :

How do I get the actual `T` of `interface IMonitor<in T> where T:IEvent`, i.e. `AConcreteEvent` if the `event` is `AConcreteMonitor<AConcreteEvent>()` in that foreach loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I typed the question and 'yahoogled' some things along the way, I found that I'm in a position to use a generic method and then just query `typeof(T)`

```
void Trigger<T>(IEvent event) where T:IMonitor<IEvent>

foreach (var monitor in monitors.Where(m=> m.GetType() == typeof(T)))
{
    monitor.Notify(event);
}
```

Simple!

Just in case someone has a similar problem...